# Disable access logs per-container in Traefik

Tags: docker, traefik

We have a very chatty container that is quickly filling the Traefik access logs.

Is there a label which we can apply which will instruct Traefik to **not** log access for a specific container?

Comment: Are you providing `--accesslog` argument while starting traefik? You need to remove it.

Comment: That would disable all access logs in traefik? I'm after per-container log settings.

Comment: I do not know about per-container access log settings. I could not find anything in the documentation about it. But it is possible to filter logs according to status code or request duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue as well, and my solution was to send all output to fluentd and then drop lines matching certain criteria. Note that depending on the volume of logs you might consider shipping to a separate machine.

Also, this request seems a good candidate for a feature request.

Comment: Agreed - I'll work out how to submit a feature request for this.

Comment: Feature requests are through Github issues. Logged as https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/6369

Comment: Wow. Too bad you got negged on it. Seems it is a hard no, so this answer stands for now. https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/6369#issuecomment-590957093